# Android Session Management

Tags: android, sql

I am making an app the stores all data in SQLite, I have DBhelper class, AdapterControl class which holds all my action such as insertUser() to add a new user to database.

My question is the login process, it is similar to sharedpreferences but how can I keep unique user session. SO when the user log in it checks db for his username and pass, if its correct it will load the activity how can i uniquely identify that user so it will return the data that he has added into the database when he request it?

```
AdapterControl control;
public void onClick(View v) {
    String username= insertusername.getText().toString();
    String password = insertpassword.getText().toString();
    if(control.checkuser(username) && control.checkpass(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
```

AdapterControl

```
public string checkuser(String username){
}

public string checkpass(String username){
}
```

How can I write this query to check the user exist and if so check if the password is right

Comment: i guess that user has unique id on the server so when you log in you can place it :)

Comment: Are you saying you have a database on each device to store their info or is every user being registered to a central database?

Comment: @matt I have SQLite as my database

Comment: When the user logs in use a POST method to flip a bool in the database and in the activity use GET method to retrieve the information if that bool is 1. Then upon logout use POST to flip the bool back to 0.

Comment: @Matt hey thanks, I understand but how would I write that do I do it in the Main Activity after the user has logged on? can you write it out